# Is "row jumping" in an API a violation of "single responsibility"?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, api, api-design

http://librdf.org/rasqal/docs/api/rasqal-section-query-results.html describes an API for enumerating rows (consisting of several values) of data.

In this API there is retrieval of values from the current row and "jumping" to the next row.

In my opinion, this is a misdesign. It violates the rule of single responsibility: the same object is responsible for enumerating to the next row and for retrieving values from the row. Do you agree that it violates SRP?

It seems for me that the right design would be to retrieve rows objects (which are not elaborated in the present version of the API) and use row objects to retrieve values.

Aside single responsibility, which other rules (if any) of good software design this API violates?

(I am writing bindings for this C API in Ada programming language, so I think of wrapping it into elaborate object oriented wrapper.)

Comment: I don't think that SRP can be violated at the API level. Think of facade design pattern: when you read the interface description, you may think that your object is dealing with a lot of responsibilities, but it is simply delegating responsibilities (that's his responsibility). It is similar with an API.

Comment: You're over-applying SRP.  SRP is a *principle* (not a mandate) that Bob Martin coined, which only applies to classes in an OO paradigm; you can't meaningfully apply it to anything else.  Further, SRP doesn't mean "Do only one thing."

Comment: @RobertHarvey The code which I discuss is object oriented despite of being written in a language (C) without explicit OO support

Comment: Be very careful. If you layer an API that deals with row objects over this API, your users may be tempted to try accessing a row object after retrieving the next one. But the underlying cursor-based API does not support this use case, which means either your row objects get invalidated, or you have to cache every value in the row object just in case it gets accessed later. The latter case is a disaster for performance, the former is a trap for the user to write hard-to-detect bugs.

Answer (score 5):

In your approach of the problem, there are essentially two types of objects: a row and an iterator over a sequence of rows. A row should have a knowledge of its contents, its values. An iterator should have a knowledge of rows, and only rows, not their contents.

Looking at the documentation, it seems to me that the authors of Rasqal RDF Query Library used a different approach. There are no two objects, but only one: the *cursor*. The cursor has a knowledge of the current entry, and it also has a knowledge of the next entry.

While your approach is more familiar to many developers, the cursor is still commonly used in data access libraries, such as the libraries which deal with SQL. Those libraries don't usually use the iterator pattern, and only provide the caller with a cursor which has two methods: one for reading the contents of the current row of the database; the other one for moving to the next row.

If the object-oriented wrapper is intended for developers who are mostly unfamiliar with low-level SQL access libraries, but who know well how to work with iterators, use iterator pattern.

If, on the other hand, you are writing your wrapper for developers who are familiar with SQL and the concept of cursors, stick with the second representation. An iterator puts probably too much abstraction over the C API, and may quickly become a leaky interface.

Comment: It's called the "iterator pattern" (if you believe [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern)), not the "enumerator pattern."

Answer (score 3):

Your view of "single responsibility" is much, much, much too narrow. The chef in a restaurant is responsible for producing breakfast, lunch, dinner, including starters, main courses and afters. That's his or her single responsibility. You don't have five different chefs for this. Or a different chef whose responsibility it is to produce one particular dinner.

The API is responsible for giving you access to the database. That's it's single responsibility, and that is what it does. If it also calculated moon phases, that would be against the Single Responsibility Principle.